# AWS Lambda updates on Firebase

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, real-time-updates

I am using AWS Lambda in order to have real-time updates on Firebase. When my user clicks on a button, it triggers the function in AWS Lambda to update my firebase.

However, this update takes really long cause I am doing it for many users. Initially, when I did with 1, it worked well around 3 secs. However, after including all users (33) it takes around 1 minute.

So my question is, is there anyway to only update firebase from AWS Lambda, if there's a change in the data? If there's no change, I wouldn't have to update and take up time.

Thank you for the help in advance! (:

Comment: Can you share your code snippet. That would help identify the issue more clearly. BTW I faced similar issue when I scaled up from 100's of users to 50k users. We resolved by breaking the request into multiple nodes.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thank you! I mainly create the charts and write them into firebase: 
    def write_message(userID, course, cardType, chart_name, value):
      destination = '/' + userID + '/' + course + "/" + cardType + "/" + chart_name + "/data.json"
      url = firebaseProject + destination
      resp = requests.put(url=url, data=json.dumps(value))

but i realised that the updates will take slow but it doesn't affect the application so it's fine!